Why do results from various experiments with different % of features selected through RFE for SVM-based classification yield inconsistent outcomes?
I now have a basic understanding of classifiers such as Random Forests, Gradient Boosted Trees, and Support Vector Machines. My tasks involve classifying layer stacks that consist of optical and radar satellite imagery, where the bands represent features. The goal is to differentiate various land use and land cover classes, such as forests, agricultural land, water bodies, and others.
My current focus involves classifying layer stacks that consist of optical and radar satellite imagery, where the individual bands serve as critical features. The objective is to effectively differentiate among various land use and land cover classes, such as forests, agricultural land, water bodies, and others.
I am analyzing a substantial dataset composed of samples that represent spectral values linked to specific classes. To refine the models, I am applying Recursive Feature Elimination across multiple scenarios for each classifier, utilizing 70%, 80%, 90%, and 100% of the features in the retraining process. The initial results indicate that the performance of both Random Forests and Gradient Boosted Trees remains more or less consistent, with the relative importance of features demonstrating stability across different scenarios. In contrast, the performance of Support Vector Machines reveals significant variability in feature importances based on the scenario, highlighting a distinct operational dynamic. I would welcome any insights or feedback you may have regarding these findings.



Welcome to CV.SE. 1. You aren't doing something inherently wrong in my view, what you see is not unexpected. Please see my answer below where I expand on this.


What measure(s) of feature importances are you using?

This is somewhat expected.
Both Gradient Boosting Machines and Random Forest can self-select by choosing the best features to make split upon. As such, RF and GBM methods tend to show stable feature importance as their tree-based base learners, identify influential features based on their utility in the ensemble of splits.
On the contrary, an SVM uses all available features for constructing its decision boundary and even if we regularised its fitting (e.g. via the $C$ or $\gamma$ hyperparameters to influence the final decision boundary) we potentially are influenced by less important and/or collinear features. And that can lead to unstable results for our feature importances as the one you observed.

Thanks! This answer is helpful.
